# Is there hotkey to quickly type the github's own hint message when committing change?

Tags: git, github

Github gives a basic hint for commit message "-m" when making changes, like this:

I type [hotkey] - it fills the commit message with "Update readme.md"
[image: k]

I wonder if it's possible to type some hotkey and it will fill the field with the hint's text?

Comment: Remember that these comments are *documentation* and like comments in your code this commit messages should not repeat the obvious, but tell the reader **why** this commit exists, i.e. what was implemented and how it relates to the requirements.

Comment: ahh, i see, typing generic obvious commit msgs is actually against the function of them

Comment: @TimothyTruckle, u can give an answer, i will accepp it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that these comments are *documentation* and like comments in your code this commit messages should not repeat the obvious.

Instead they should tell the reader **why** this commit exists, i.e. what *behavior* was implemented or changed and how this change relates to the requirements.